# Create a VirtualBox VM from an existing bare metal Windows installation

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine

I have Windows 8.1 installed on one computer. I want to use it as a VM under VirtualBox on another computer. Is this possible? If so then how?

All I'm trying to do is save a ton of time going through the installation process of all the software I already have installed on the existing 8.1 machine. If there's another way to do a fresh 8.1 install on a VirtualBox VM and then clone all the software installations from the original machine to the new VM then that would also achieve my objectives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use VMware Workstation to virtualize a physical machine. It comes with 30 day trial
2. [Convert VMware to Virtual box VM](http://www.howtogeek.com/125640/how-to-convert-virtual-machines-between-virtualbox-and-vmware/)